# blur() does not work programmatically | but does when initiated from the user

Tags: javascript

This works in clearing in input after a user submits it via ajax on a single input form.

```
var tweet_input = document.getElementById( 'tweet_input' );
tweet_input.value='';
tweet_input.blur();
```

However on a 3 input field orm this does not:

```
var input_url = document.getElementById( 'bookmark_input_url' );
    input_url.value='';
var input_title = document.getElementById( 'bookmark_input_title' );
    input_title.value='';
var input_tag = document.getElementById( 'bookmark_input_tag' );
    input_tag.value='';

input_title.blur();
input_url.blur();
input_tag.blur();
```

Only the last element is actually blurred.  Not sure what is going on here with the other two or how to troubleshoot.

Basically I have Event Listeners that fire on a blur(), they work fine on an actual user blur(), but when I try to initiate them programmatically only one works.

Comment: `blur()` is the opposite of `focus()`. There can only be one element with focus, therefore you can only blur the last focussed element. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Needs to have focus first.

```
input_title.focus();
input_title.blur();
...
```

Comment: Sounds like a hack but I'll try it.

Comment: This accurately imitates the user's action (focus first, then blur), so it's not really a hack.  If the element doesn't have focus, the blur event won't fire.

Comment: The first 2 need focus....not the final input field...the form considers only the last entry to be in focus...I guess this makes sense...thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a working demo here if it helps (sorry for the alerts, was rushing) http://jsfiddle.net/3PdcW/1/

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in my case:

```
const fireEvent = (element, eventType="blur") => element && element.dispatchEvent(new Event(eventType));
```

Now we can call this function from wherever we want to fire any event attached to any element.

```
fireEvent(input_title)
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)